# Get first object from Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

Given the following code:

```
randomItemQS = Item.objects.filter().exclude(id__in=[o.id for o in collection]).order_by('?')
randomItem = randomItemQS[:1]
calculation = randomItem.method() / constant
```

How can I ensure that `randomItem` is an `Item` and not a QuerySet?

If I run the code from `manage.py shell`, then I get the expected result. However, running this code from a view results in the AttributeError `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'method'`, and indicates that the error happens on the final line.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Sorry, I should be more specific -- I have this working just fine in the shell, but it's not working in the view. What would be different?

Comment: See Pavel's answer below.

Comment: Not related, but if `collection` is itself a queryset you should just do `exclude(id__in=collection)`, which uses a subquery and removes the need for evaluating collection separately.

Comment: `collection` is a list, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Just index it, slicing adds a LIMIT query to the QS without executing it:

```
randomItem = randomItemQS[0]
```

Comment: This changes the error message to `IndexError: list index out of range` for some reason. Not sure why... the QuerySet returns over 150 objects.

Comment: Are you sure? `print randomItemQS.count()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
randomItem=None
randomItemQS = Item.objects.filter().exclude(id__in=[o.id for o in collection]).order_by('?')[:1]
if randomItemQS:
   randomItem = randomItemQS[0]
   calculation = randomItem.method() / constant
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question was regarding the difference between a view and a shell window, the correct answer is to convert parameters passed to the view to an integer to ensure the query returns objects as expected.

Other answers have been upvoted accordingly as they are valid. Thanks.